# Creating an div that shadows behind another div

Tags: html, css, user-interface, shadow

How can I create the navy div here that hovers behind the modal? How can i link it so its position is relative to the modal? Should I use ::after? What is this even called?

https://www.uidesigndaily.com/posts/figma-cookie-preferences-modal-cookies-settings-day-1581

Many more examples can be seen on https://www.uidesigndaily.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

:hover is acctually "hover" and ::after is the oposide of ::before